# What is a 3(21) or 3(38) fiduciary? [321, 338]

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan

My financial guy mentioned different kinds of fiduciaries by number, 3(21) and 3(38). What do they mean? Where are they defined?

Answer (score 2):

The numbers reference sections in the U.S. Employee Retirement Income Security Act of 1974, or ERISA, which is the major law governing the operation of employee benefit plans. They appear in the definitions section of subchapter I, the text is hosted [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/29/1002), and describe responsibilities to employee welfare/benefit plans.

Section 3(21) - Fiduciary for plan management. Has authority for management and disposition of assets in the plan, can appoint and monitor a 3(38) investment manager. Renders investment advice for a fee (or other compensation).

Section 3(38) - Fiduciary for asset management. Has full discretionary control to manage, acquire, or dispose of any asset of a plan. Must be a registered investment advisor, bank, or other qualified entity.

References:

- [3(21) Versus 3(38) ERISA Investment Fiduciaries — Decoding the Numbers](https://www.nipa.org/blogpost/1011572/169845/3-21-Versus-3-38-ERISA-Investment-Fiduciaries--Decoding-the-Numbers)
- [Wikipedia - Employee Retirement Income Security Act of 1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employee_Retirement_Income_Security_Act_of_1974)